# Q_PROPERTY WRITE get index

Tags: c++, qt, qmetaobject

I have this property:

> ```
> Q_PROPERTY(int _a READ a WRITE setA NOTIFY aChanged)
> ```

I know only the property's name `_a`. I would like get the index of the method `setA`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out `QMetaObject::indexOfProperty(const char * name)` and `QMetaProperty QMetaObject::property(int index)`. They will allow you to access the property by name.

AFAIK there is now way to access a setter method via the corresponding property.

Comment: Yes but, when you have the QProperty how get the index of the write method?

Comment: There is a write() method in QProperty, isn't this enough? I don't know a way how to actually get the function itself.

Comment: No, it isn't enough. There is QMetaMethod QMetaProperty::notifySignal(). I would like QMetaMethod QMetaProperty::writeMethod().

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to access the setter this way. I updated my answer so you can accept it if no actual solution arises. Maybe you should add a suggestion to the Qt bug-tracker (however I have the impression that most suggestions and even many bug reports are ignored since Digia is responsible for Qt).